# saxon9EE - javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet

Tags: vb.net, saxon

I am trying to transform our system data (in xml format) to defined output xml file.

To create this output xml, I am planning to use XSLT version 2.0. Hence I'm using Saxon EE evaluation version (SaxonEE9-5-1-2 version)

I am trying to demonstrate this software to my team thereby buy the software and use the features and functionality of XSLT 2.0, XQuery, etc

Currently I am working on a prototype project - where I am having problem.

VB.NET Transformation code is as follows:

```
    Dim strXSLT As String = String.Empty
    Dim strXML As String = String.Empty

    'Retrieve data from database as string
    strXML = GetData()

    Dim processor As Saxon.Api.Processor = New Saxon.Api.Processor()
        Dim builder As Saxon.Api.DocumentBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder()

    'Retrieve XSLT file content from database as string
    strXSLT = GetXSLT()

    'Convert XSLT string data as memorystream
        Dim byteDataXSLT() As Byte
        byteDataXSLT = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXSLT)
    Dim msXSLT As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteDataXSLT,0, byteDataXSLT.Length)

    'Convert XML string data as memorystream
        Dim byteDataXML() As Byte
        byteDataXML = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML)
    Dim msXML As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteDataXML,0, byteDataXML.Length)

    'Save the xml file before processing
    Dim fsXML As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\Temp\XML.xml", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim byteFileXML() As Byte
    byteFileXML = msXML.ToArray()
    fsXML.Write(byteFileXML, 0, byteFileXML.Length)

    'Save the xsl file before processing
    Dim fsXSLT As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\Temp\XSL.xslt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim byteFileXSLT() As Byte
    byteFileXSLT = msXSLT.ToArray()
    fsXSLT.Write(byteFileXSLT, 0, byteFileXSLT.Length)

    Dim sURI As New Uri("file:///C:/")

    builder.BaseUri = sURI


    Dim input As Saxon.Api.XdmNode = builder.Build(msXML)
    Dim transformer As Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(msXSLT).Load()

        transformer.InitialContextNode = input
        Dim serializer As New Saxon.Api.Serializer()
        serializer.SetOutputFile(strOutputFileName)
        transformer.Run(serializer)
```

I am getting below error on below line, only when I run through program. When I do the transformation manually i am not getting this error.

```
Dim transformer As Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(msXSLT).Load()
```

Error Message:

```
saxon9ee javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet.
```

But when I saved the xml and xslt memorystream to filestream and do the transformation manually, we get the desired output.

We are trying to figure out the root cause of this issue, but no luck.

Any details on this error message would be really helpful and very much appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Many Thanks in advance

Raghu

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not seeing the error messages produced by the compiler. If you aren't running from the Console, then set the ErrorList property on the XsltCompiler, and when the exception occurs, inspect and display the errors somewhere, e.g. send them to a log file or pop up a window containing them.

Without seeing the error message, I can't begin to guess what the error might be.